# Creating a queue for few delegates

Tags: objective-c

I have a few calls that should return delegate respond. The calls can be made in parallel. I have to start the program only when all the calls are done .

I was thinking about the right way to do that , and my main idea was to set a integer, that when a delegate is done,that integer is incremented ,and when its equals X i am start.

Question is, if the incrementing will be atomic, or is it have to be synchronised.

```
    -(void)serverDelegate1:(NSMutableArray*)images
    integer++;
//check

    -(void)serverDelegate2:(NSMutableArray*)images
    integer++;
//check

    -(void)serverDelegate3:(NSMutableArray*)images
    integer++;
//check
```

and set a timeout so after a while it starts anyway.

It might be a complete wrong way , so forgive me for that .

Comment: Will each delegate be a separate instance of the same class?  If so incrementing a integer in the instance won't work; you need to control this from "outside".

Comment: no, each delegate is another class that connect another server .

Comment: Isn't that "yes"?  Each is a separate instance (of the same or different class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about using a Concurrent queue ? Like in this example :

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

// Add a task to the group
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
   // Some asynchronous work
});

// Do some other work while the tasks execute.

// When you cannot make any more forward progress,
// wait on the group to block the current thread.
dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

// Release the group when it is no longer needed.
dispatch_release(group);
```

You can create the queue in the delegate, and wait for the three tasks to be completed ?

More information can be found in Apple documentation : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html